# Concatenate a variable within a loop

Tags: makefile

I'm stuck to concatenate a variable within a for loop in my Makefile.
I have a variable that contains `gcc` flags for header files `-I` and an array of dependencies names that I'd like to add to the variable within a for loop.
I don't know if I'm crystal clear so let me show you the part of the Makefile. (unrelated pieces removed)

```
IFL  := -I ./inc

...

LIBS = libX libY libZ

...

libraries:
    @for i in $(LIBS); do        \
        IFL += -I ./$(LIBD)/$$i; \ # PROBLEM ?
        make -C $(LIBD)/$$i ;    \
    done
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can modify variables in recipes; it never worked for me. If you move that loop to before the recipe it will probably work.

Comment: would you have a problem doing `IFL += $(foreach lib, $(LIBS), -I ./$(LIBD)/$(lib))` outside the recipe and then doing the for loop to execute `make -C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I wouldn't suggest a for loop here, I would strongly suggest making `libraries = ${LIBS}` in this case or creating the rule straight for `${LIBS}`. this way you can make alterations per target, and the recipes can get executed in parallel.
2. When that's the case you can do something slightly more sensical like so

   LIBS = libX libY libZ

   ${LIBS} : 
       CFLAGS = -I ./${LIBD}/$@ make -C ${LIBD}/${@}

   Key caveat here is that you have to change to 'add' to `CFLAGS` instead of straight simple assignment, or if you really need them separated, replace my usage of `CFLAGS` with `IFL`, and change `IFL := -I ./inc` to be `IFL += -I ./inc`
3. If you don't export the variable it won't be communited to your submake no matter what you are doing.

Better Ideas:
You have a makefile already sitting in the directory `${LIBD}/$@` because `make -C` works; why can't you handle adding this include path there? OR always have your builds include the current directory if you are trying to be more generic.

You could also look at target specific variables.

So while I think you are solving the wrong problem, ( i.e. instead of asking about the real problem you are trying to solve you are asking about an issue trying to solve it a specific way) I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Makefile's [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html). You will probably need either `subst()` or `patsubst()`. For example, for the case described above it would be:

```
LIBS = x y z
FLAGS = $(patsubst %, -I ./${LIBD}/%, ${LIBS})
```